# useState is not updating in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have state

```
 const [editMode,editModeSwitch]  = React.useState<boolean>(false)
```

I'm trying to render `h1` if the editMode is true but my button doesnt seem to do anything,
Any suggestions?
Here is my code :

```
return (
    editModeSwitch ? (
        <div id="card" className="card">
          <div id="postButtons" className="buttons">
            <button onClick={() => history.push("/homepage")}>Home</button>
            <button onClick={() => history.push("/profile")}>My Profile</button>
            <button onClick={() => LogOut()}>Log Out</button>
          </div>
          <div className="posts">
            <p>
              Title :
              {grabTitleFromLocation()}
            </p>

            <p>
              Description :
              {grabDescriptionFromLocation()}
            </p>
            <button onClick={() => {deletePost(grabIdFromLocation())}}>Delete Post</button>
            <button onClick={() => {editModeSwitch(true)}}>Edit Post</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    ) : (
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    )
  );
};
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `return (editMode ? ...` instead of `return (editModeSwitch ? ...` ?

Comment: The error i get from TS is `TS2349: This expression is not callable.   Type 'Boolean' has no call signatures.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editModeSwitch` is the function you call to update the `editMode`. So, it should be `editMode`, not `editModeSwitch` in the return statement.

```
return (
  editMode ? ( // update this
    <div id="card" className="card">
      <div id="postButtons" className="buttons">
        <button onClick={() => history.push("/homepage")}>Home</button>
        <button onClick={() => history.push("/profile")}>My Profile</button>
        <button onClick={() => LogOut()}>Log Out</button>
      </div>
      <div className="posts">
        <p>
          Title :
          {grabTitleFromLocation()}
        </p>

        <p>
          Description :
          {grabDescriptionFromLocation()}
        </p>
        <button onClick={() => {deletePost(grabIdFromLocation())}}>Delete Post</button>
        <button onClick={() => {editModeSwitch(true)}}>Edit Post</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  )
 );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `useState` wrong

`const [editMode,editModeSwitch]  = React.useState<boolean>(false)`

should be

`const [editMode,setEditMode]  = React.useState<boolean>(false)`

Please read it here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

More example from official docs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```